# Python: ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 1

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to execute a query to search 3 tables in a database using MySQL through Python. Every time I try and execute the following string as a query, it gives me an error about concatenation in the string.

```
"SELECT fileid FROM files WHERE description LIKE '%" + search + "%' OR filename LIKE '%" + search + "%' OR uploader LIKE '%" + search + "%' ORDER BY fileid DESC"
```

This is the error it gives me:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 1
```

If I remove the character it asks for then I have to also remove the %, which stops the query from actually working properly. What can I do to fix this, since I'm rather new to Python.

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: Use the built in string substitution tools for your SQL tool instead of trying to build the query string yourself with standard Python string mechanics.  It works better that way.  Are you using MySQLdb?

Comment: Yes I'm using MySQLdb, and where can I find these substitution tools?

Comment: The docs at http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes say, "Note that any literal percent signs in the query string passed to execute() must be escaped, i.e. %%." Are you using `execute()`? The substitution tools @Silas mentioned are shown at http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples

Comment: Please check, if the answer below still works (for Python 3.5+). Didn't worked for me, it tried it different.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

It looks like python is interpreting the % as a printf-like format character. Try using %%?

```
"SELECT fileid 
FROM files 
WHERE description LIKE '%%%s%%' 
    OR filename LIKE '%%%s%%' 
    OR uploader LIKE '%%%s%%' 
    ORDER BY fileid DESC" % (search, search, search)
```

Comment: To be exact, MySQLdb uses the **%** operator to put parameters into the query, therefor any single **%** character in the query string is interpreted as the start of a argument specifier. To prevent this use _%%_ for _%_ in queries. Please see also the appropriate documentation: [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: this fix applies to postgresql too.

Answer (score 3):

Just for you info: I tried the solution of @Pochi today, in Python 3.6, and for some reason it provoked not expected behaviour. I had two, and three arguments for format string, so at the end was:

```
% (Search, Search)
```

My string ("search") began with an upper "S". I got the error message:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'S' (0x53) at index 113
```

I changed uppercase to lowercase, and the error was:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Then I just put my arguments inside of double %% at the beginning and the end, and it worked. So my code looked like:

```
"SELECT fileid 
FROM files 
WHERE description LIKE '%%search%%' 
    OR filename LIKE '%%search%%'
    ORDER BY fileid DESC"
```

Another solution would be the one provided by @Alice Yuan. She just doubled the percentage sings, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
query = """SELECT id, name FROM provice WHERE name LIKE %s"""
cursor.execute(query, '%%%s%%' % name)
```

I think it's easy way to fix this issue!

Comment: Ehm, you know that the `%%%s%%' % name` part is completely unnecessary?... The parameter of the query is the `%s` which is replaced by the ORM or what ever DB abstraction you are using...

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to add the LIKE wildcard character `%` to the value. This correctly quotes and escapes the LIKE pattern.

In Python 3.6+ you can use an f-string to include the LIKE wildcard character `%` in the value which correctly inserts the escaped string value into the SQL:

```
# string to find, e.g.,
search = 'find-me'

# Parameterised SQL template
sql = """SELECT fileid FROM files
WHERE description LIKE %s OR filename LIKE %s OR uploader LIKE %s
ORDER BY fileid DESC"""

# Combine LIKE wildcard with search value
like_val = f'%{search}%'

# Run query with correctly quoted and escaped LIKE pattern
cursor.execute(sql, (like_val, like_val, like_val))
```

[python3](/questions/tagged/python3) [mysql-python](/questions/tagged/mysql-python)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
SELECT fileid 
FROM files 
WHERE description LIKE '%%%%%s%%%%' 
OR filename LIKE '%%%%%s%%%%' 
OR uploader LIKE '%%%%%s%%%%' 
ORDER BY fileid DESC" % (search, search, search)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this answers the question?

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution in 2024 is `sqlalchemy.text`, this method keep sql string the same as it should be.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
sqlstr = "SELECT fileid FROM files WHERE description LIKE '%" + search + "%' OR filename LIKE '%" + search + "%' OR uploader LIKE '%" + search + "%' ORDER BY fileid DESC"

conn = sa.create_engine("xxxxx")
conn.execute(sa.text(sqlstr))
```